# How to highlight specific dates in datepicker on Android

Tags: android-datepicker

I need to develop an application that checks a database and highlights the dates which have any record on this database (something like [this](http://www.spiceforms.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/11.png)). I have done some research about it but the method that I found is colorizing background of day manually.